# Does QGIS support Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 4G LTE?

Tags: qgis, mobile, tablet

I need a tablet for outdoor work and i would like to know if this device "Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 4G LTE" works fine with QGIS mobile application.

Comment: Have you tried QField?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1, no 4G though.  I tried to install QGIS and was able to.  However, the main panel was missing (Project, Edit, View, etc) so I couldn't find a way to connect to the GPS.  From the information I've gathered, it is buggy and seems to not install properly and/or work at all but seems to be getting better.

Here are some useful resources I found:

A wiki site for QGIS/Android, http://hub.qgis.org/

This is more of open source solutions website.  They have a section dedicated to QGIS/Android; http://www.opengis.ch/android-gis/

If you are going to attempt to install QGIS on your Android device, you'll need Ministro, which is a free download at the Play Store

Answer (score 0):

You may try NextGIS mobile. This is native Android application with good QGIS integration.

[image]

The documentation is here: http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngmobile/source/toc.html

For collaborating field work I also recommend nextgis.com web GIS. It free and also [has integration with QGIS](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/ngqgis_connect.html) (via NextGIS Connect plugin) and Mobile (native).

[image]